# Need to prevent a website link from being displayed in Bing search results

Tags: bing

I have a web application that shows up in the Bing search. I do not want the application link to show up in Bing search. In the application root directory we have a robots.txt file that contains the following:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: bingbot
Disallow: /
```

However the link still shows up in Bing search. I also tried using this tag in the header section for specific web pages:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
```

However the link is still displayed in bing search. We did wait for 2-3 weeks and more but the links are still appearing.

We contacted Bing Webmaster tools support and they suggested that for a URL to be removed from their index it has to be deleted from our site so that the URL returns a 404 (Not Found) or 410 (Gone) HTTP status. They also mentioned that in order for Bing to detect that the page has in fact been removed from the site and is now returning a 404 or 410 HTTP status code, Bingbot needs to be able to access the URL, so we should not block the URL from being re-crawled through robots.txt.

Now the problem here is that we cannot delete our site or redirect it to 404 error page since it is used by our client. Google search does not show the link  but bing shows it. Is there any other way by which we can make the link(s) to not appear in bing search?

Comment: Did you find the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that from the bing console if you need quick removal: https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/block-urls-from-bing-264e560a

Have a look at the last paragraph on blocking URL's immediately.

Comment: I did try the Block URLs option in bing webmaster a while back for the same link but for some reason it didn't work. The link still showed up in search and then the time period expired. The block feature in google works though. I have now extended that block in bing, not sure if it will make any difference. Is there anything else that I can try?

Comment: If the feature isn't working as intended I would suggest contacting Bing to raise the problem. It's not an ideal solution.

Comment: @Sunil additionally you could do some referrer snooping on your website, when you detect bing just kill the page and return a 404. Edit: This will require your site to be on HTTPS to receive referrer data from other HTTPS sites.